# Getting XML node value and all nested column nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have here a small extract of the XML files I will have to handle:

```
<garRoot fileMaster="9371034.0582.30582">
  <garTransactions>
    <garTransaction InnerTransId="89274503">
      <garSection>
        <garSectionCounterFName />
        <garColumns />
        <garSection>
          <garSectionName>Header Section</ChapterName>
          <garSectionCounterFName />
          <garColumns />
          <garSection>
            <garSectionName>Startup</ChapterName>
            <garSectionCounterFName />
            <garColumns>
              <garColumn>
                <garColText>Idea Date:</garColText>
                <garColVal>2017-03-22</garColVal>
              </garColumn>
              <garColumn>
                <garColText>Idea Name:</garColText>
                <garColVal>The Invisible Cloak</garColVal>
              </garColumn>
            </garColumns>
          </garSection>
```

I have tried some code to attempt to:

1. Start with getting the `InnerTransId` values for each `garTransaction`:

   `SELECT
   T.value('./@InnerTransID','varchar(50)') As InnerTransID
   FROM @XML.nodes('//garTransaction') AS GarT(T)`
2. Because in reality there have been nested `garSection` in other `garSection` I've tried to get all `garColText` and `garColVal` via `garColumn`:

   `SELECT
   C.query('./garColText') As cText
   , C.query('./garColVal') As cVal
   FROM @XML.nodes('//garColumn') as garC(C)`

Where I'm having trouble is, as an example I know I have 145 columns for each transaction id but i cannot seem to link the data together, as I would need to have returned:

```
InnerTransId    cText       cVal
--------------- ----------- ------------------- 
89274503        Idea Date:  2017-03-22
89274503        Idea Name:  The Invisible Cloak
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` for that purpose :

```
SELECT
    T.value('@InnerTransID','varchar(50)') As InnerTransID
    , C.value('garColText[1]','varchar(max)') As cText
    , C.value('garColVal[1]','varchar(max)') As cVal
FROM @XML.nodes('//garTransaction') AS GarT(T)
    OUTER APPLY T.nodes('.//garColumn') as garC(C)
```

Notice how `nodes('.//garColumn')` was called on `T`, so that the result, `garC(C)`, only contains `garColumn` that related to current `garTransaction`.

Comment: Thank you!!! The query worked perfectly; now I am just trying to understand it ~ I hope I can still ask a few questions while I play around with the SQL statement? -> I had tried some outer apply yesterday that was just returning 10x more rows!